# Jaya create a star pattern

Tags: java

I tried to made a star pattern but I did not know how to do it, I know how to made start pattern when the start or the spaces are continuous, but when it is a start and spaces like the pattern that I show below, I do not how to do it.

```
 *   *
  * *
   * 
  * *
 *   *
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What have you tried so far? Please show some of your attempts.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include some code you have tried so far and sample output. Format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: In the current state, it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the relationship between the corners of the cross/star. Take this star for example of size 5.

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 *       *
1   *   *
2     *
3   *   *
4 *       *
```

In a cross in the diagonal from (0,0) to (4,4), the indices are the same (in the code this means row == col).

Also, you can notice that in the diagonal from (0,4) to (4,0) indices always sum up to 4, which is size - 1 (in the code this is row + col == size - 1).

Therefore in the code, you will need to loop through rows and then through columns. Each time you have to check if the above conditions are fulfilled.

**Code:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCross(5); // Vertical size of cross
    }

    public static void printCross(int size) {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                if (row == col || row + col == size - 1) {
                    System.out.print('*');
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be a much useful answer if you explain the OP what are doing here.

Comment: Instead of just showing code, you should also explain what the code does and why it is solving the problem. With this answer, the OP doesn't learn anything.
**Edit:** seems @TDG was faster :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I see what the code does, I really tried to do it several times but I never found the pattern.